# Es correcto Almacenar la información FirebaseDatabase de una llave en una clase estática Java?

Tags: javascript, android, base-de-datos, firebase

Para hacer muchas llamadas a la base de datos, utilizo una clase llamada `firebaseHelper` en donde se hace la petición a los nodos que necesito.
No se si esta se una mala practica, lo hago mas que todo para separar la capa de datos del negocio.

```
public class FirebaseDatabaseHelper {
    private static ArrayList<User> users;

public void retrieveUsers()
    {
        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    fetchUserData(dataSnapshot);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

private void fetchUserData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        users.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            User usuario=ds.getValue(User.class);
            users.add(usuario);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El uso de DAOs es una practica muy común y recomendada

un DAO es un objeto que proporciona una interfaz abstracta a algún tipo de base de datos u otro mecanismo de persistencia.Un DAO se puede utilizar en un gran porcentaje de las aplicaciones, que requieran almacenamiento de datos. DAO oculta todos los detalles de almacenamiento del resto de la aplicación, actuando como intermediario entre la aplicación y la base de datos.

Esta capta de abstracción proporciona algunas operaciones de datos específicos sin exponer a los detalles de la base de datos. 
Como resultado de ello, los mecanismos de acceso a los datos se pueden cambiar independientemente del código que utiliza los datos.

Además permite cambiar ciertos aspectos del programa después con mayor facilidad, por ejemplo cambiar el modelo de base de datos